# How do I disable user input on a WebView?

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime

I'm having tons of issues trying to integrate Microsoft's `WebView` in my WinRT application and one of them is the following. I want to display the `WebView` and its content (which comes from a local offline server but that works like a charm) and I don't want the user to be able to click around ; basically completely disable user input on this `WebView`.

There is no `IsEnabled` property on this control so I tried:

- Catching the many Pressed-like events and setting the `Handled` property of the `event` object to `false` in each one of the handlers
- Catching the `GotFocus` event of the `WebView` to set the focus on another control immediately
- Putting the WebView in a `ContentControl`, then set the `IsEnabled` property of the `ContentControl` to `false`

Obviously, none of these workarounds did work so I'm facing a brickwall here. Maybe some of you can help find a solution?

More details if that can help: the web page that is loaded contains an HTML5 canvas where the user can draw things (like in Microsoft Paint). There are also links (`ahref`). I dont want the user to be able to draw on this canvas, and I don't want them to be able to click on these links as well!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a if the content is not animated then you can use a Rectangle instead of the WebView and in the rectangle you use a WebViewBrush, this actually take the webview and render it's content as an image on the rectangle. since it is an image no interaction is available on the rectangle, but if you have animation then you will lose them. 
Generally this trick is used to show content onto the webview.

Comment: Unfortunately the content **is** animated so I can't do that (though I thought about it...)

Comment: unfortunately webview are not very developer friendly controls :( I had to battle with them a lot too. If you have access to the source of the page probably your best bet is to disable event through javascript